# I am getting msg element does not exit for an XPATH

Tags: vba, xpath

I am working on a web form fill project . I have a pre populated table in which I have to fill data/ select data on different fields in a row. I am able to fill data in a particular row. But when I try to select from a drop down list in the same row it says element does not exist whereas I am able to click the element .

I have tried

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//td[contains(text(),'ABC')]/td[18]").SendKeys "XYZ"
```

also

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//td[contains(text(),'ABC')]/following-sibling::td[18]").SendKeys "XYZ"
```

and

```
bot.FindElementByXPath("//td[contains(text(),'ABC')]/td[18]/input").SendKeys "XYZ"
```

But nothing seem to work.

Any one who could help in this case.

Relevant Html codes are as follows

```html
<td class="gridtext" align="center">
                                                                    <select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdUsers$ctl02$ddlResult" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$grdUsers$ctl02$ddlResult\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_grdUsers_ctl02_ddlResult" class="Dropdown" style="width:100px;">
       <option selected="selected" value="1">1-Promoted</option>
       <option value="2">2-Repeater</option>
       <option value="3">3-Discontinued</option>

      </select>
                                                                </td>
```

Comment: Try with this xpath `//td[contains(text(),'ABC')]/following-sibling::td/input`

Comment: Do you have multiple rows that contains `ABC`? If yes then you have to use `(//td[contains(text(),'ABC')]/following-sibling::td/input)[18]` means the 18th matching element.

Comment: Thanx for your prompt help Supputuri but both the solutions provided by you do not work. "ABC" is for example. The actual names are different .

Comment: Is there an url you can share or the relevant html?

Comment: Sorry, try to click with this xpath to select the 2nd item in the list box `//td[contains(text(),'ABC')]/following-sibling::td/select/option[.='2-Repeater']`

Comment: Tnanx Supputuri for yor suggestion.  I had to add ".click" at the end of the code suggested by you and it worked.